# Can I upgrade existing Neverware CloudReady to Google Chrome OS Flex?

Tags: boot, usb, virtual-machine, google-chrome-os-flex

Can I update an existing CloudReady to CloudReady 2.0 (a.k.a. Google Chrome OS Flex)? I tried changing channel to canary but still ChromeOS Flex isn't offered. So Can I update to Flex? Or do I have to wait until its stable release?

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question, but did you follow all the steps outlined in the [installation guide](https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11552529)? If so, which step exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything. I got stuck while booting, in VM, blank screen forever, and in real hardware i got stuck on chrome logo forever.

Comment: What is "everything"? 'No need to repeat what's written in the question. Which step exactly from the installation guide did you get stuck? Can you name that step?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke >> Booting from USB.

Comment: Ok, that's [step 2 then](https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11552352?hl=en&ref_topic=11551271). They write "*Press the power button.
Immediately begin repeatedly pressing your device's boot key.*" Which boot key are you using? Are you using Virtual Box for the VM by the way?

Comment: No I used Intel NUC , and I am pressing the F10 key which my BIOS is instructing to press to enter boot menu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134390/discussion-between-saaru-lindestokke-and-head).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Why not?

## Not responsible for any accidential data loss...

## Steps (remember to press enter after typing each command)

All steps are assuming that runs in CloudReady
Write the Flex image to a flash drive with Chromebook Recovery Utility

Press Ctrl+Alt+T, type shell, and hit enter

Use `ls /dev/sd*12 | sed "s/12//g"` to find the Flex installation flash drive's node and the harddisk's node (something like `/dev/sda` will be printed out, that's the node we need to find out) (if more than one result printed, the first result is your harddisk's node, the last one is the flash drive's node. If not, most likely that `/dev/nvme0n1` is your harddisk's node)

Run the following command (REPLACE  with the Flex installation drive's node and REPLACE <harddrive_node> with your harddisk's node) :

```
sudo dd if=<device node>2 of=<harddrive_node>2 bs=4M
sudo dd if=<device node>3 of=<harddrive_node>3 bs=4M
sudo dd if=<device node>4 of=<harddrive_node>4 bs=4M
sudo dd if=<device node>5 of=<harddrive_node>5 bs=4M
sudo dd if=<device node>6 of=<harddrive_node>6 bs=4M
sudo dd if=<device node>7 of=<harddrive_node>7 bs=4M
sudo dd if=<device node>12 of=<harddrive_node>12 bs=4M
```

Run `sudo reboot`, you should be rebooted to Flex now.